# Python in anaconda install packages using pip, which pip did I use?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Suppose I have several virtual env in anaconda:

base
py36
py37
py38

if I am using

```
conda activate py36
```

I am in the py36 environment, if I install using

```
conda install xxx
```

Then I knew my xxx packages will be installed under py36 folder in my virtual env.

but if I am using

```
pip install xxx
```

Where did xxx located in this case?
Most likely in py36 or base.
Which one is the default?

The second question is can we use some options to specify the folder we want it land in?

I mean even I am in py38 env, I can install xxx in base/py36 folder, if I want to.

Comment: pip will default to install things in the active conda environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which version of Python is affiliated to your *pip* install, you can run

```bash
pip --version
```

I personnaly get this output, so that is where packages should be installed:

```
pip 23.2.1 from C:\Users\ameu00\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)
```

You can choose which pip to use using the following command (on Windows or Linux):

```
path/of/python/executable -m pip install package_name
```

The `-m` parameter corresponds to a package to use (might be useful for `black` or `robot` for instance).

If you want to manually choose the installation directory you have the `--target` argument:

```
pip install --target=somewhere/other/than/the/default package_name
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you, I think you answer has everythin I need and it is thoughtful.

Answer (score 1):

if you're running the pip install from within py36, the package would've gone to that env's lib/site-packages

`pip show xxx`
will show you the location